# Adobe DTM - Get ID value from div that enters viewport (event based rule)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, adobe-analytics

How do I capture the value of the ID attribute of a div, from a specific class, that enters the viewport in "visible" state? 
When I create a "enters viewport" rule, it fires for all the divs in the source code, (given that they are within the viewport) visible or not.

I can't seem to write the condition to only fire the rule when the div is visible, or how to get the attribute ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an Event Based Rule:

- Event Type: enters viewport
- Element Tag or selector: div.specialClass //specialClass is the class you search for
- Rule Condition, Custom: `if (jQuery("div.specialClass:visible")[0] != undefined){return true;}`

Thats it, the rule will fire if the element with the specialClass will enter the viewport and is visible.

To track the ID, just use a Data Element with a CSS Selector and in this Event Based Rule reference to this Data Element.

Comment: You my friend are a life saver :) The getting the ID part didnt quite work since I'm trying to track multiple divs at the same time , but I did find a solution. Instead of a data element I just used DTMs selector syntax to get the id of any div matches the conditions above: %this.getAttribute(id)%